# Distance and Time base Calculation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, time, filter

I have too many records in database. I want to filter it based on distance and time. Is there any better way to achieve the same ? cause i have more than 100 records and call the google API for all record is not possible also i need to sort that record on basis of time and distance so there have one required param time so i need to use **google api** for sure . so any optimise way are available to do this process shortly .

```
any help of suggestions are appreciable
```

Comment: You won't get any meaningful answers unless you explain your situation in a bit more detail. What does the database look like? Can you give a small sample of the database as an example, and what would your ideal filter do to that small sample? Then explain how you have tried to implement this filter and what difficulties you have run into.

Comment: I have implemented Pythagoras algorithm but it gives straight line distance so I choose google api to find distance but it is not ideal way to call google api for each records every time.

My database have product table having filed like id,name,brand,quantity,price,description,latitude,longitude

and i want filter based on user's location